# Why is the spatial resolution of image from WorldView 3 like this?

Tags: gis, gdal

The output of this image from `gdalinfo 20141030-wv03.tif` is like this:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 20141030-wv03.tif
Size is 16484, 15253
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (113.959353776485997,23.091020758099145)
Pixel Size = (0.000002966620901,-0.000002966620901)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 113.9593538,  23.0910208) (113d57'33.67"E, 23d 5'27.67"N)
Lower Left  ( 113.9593538,  23.0457709) (113d57'33.67"E, 23d 2'44.78"N)
Upper Right ( 114.0082556,  23.0910208) (114d 0'29.72"E, 23d 5'27.67"N)
Lower Right ( 114.0082556,  23.0457709) (114d 0'29.72"E, 23d 2'44.78"N)
Center      ( 113.9838047,  23.0683958) (113d59' 1.70"E, 23d 4' 6.22"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=256
Band 2 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=256
Band 3 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=256
```

The spatial resolution is `(0.000002966620901,-0.000002966620901)`, how to understand this value?

I also check another image from WorldView 2, ths output is:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 20150708.tif
Size is 9984, 10132
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 50N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 50N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",117,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World - N hemisphere - 114°E to 120°E - by country"],
        BBOX[0,114,84,120]],
    ID["EPSG",32650]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (291153.100000000034925,2705938.760000000242144)
Pixel Size = (0.510000000000000,-0.510000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  291153.100, 2705938.760) (114d56'22.85"E, 24d27'10.88"N)
Lower Left  (  291153.100, 2700771.440) (114d56'25.58"E, 24d24'22.98"N)
Upper Right (  296244.940, 2705938.760) (114d59'23.60"E, 24d27'13.32"N)
Lower Right (  296244.940, 2700771.440) (114d59'26.26"E, 24d24'25.41"N)
Center      (  293699.020, 2703355.100) (114d57'54.57"E, 24d25'48.15"N)
Band 1 Block=9984x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=9984x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=9984x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

The spatial resolution is `(0.510000000000000,-0.510000000000000)`. How do I understand their difference between them? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are in two different coordinate systems.

Your second file `20150708.tif` is in an UTM projection ([UTM 50N](https://epsg.io/32650) to be exact) which has map units in meters - that's why the pixel resolutions is in meters (0.51m).

Your first file `20141030-wv03.tif` is in a geographic coordinate system, the widely used [World Geodetic System 1984 (or WGS84)](https://epsg.io/4326) which has map units in degrees, giving you the pixel resolution also in (decimal) degrees. On the equator 0.00001 degrees is around [1.11 meters](https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/approx_equivalents.htm) so both images have likely the same resolution.

For more info on WGS84 vs UTM, [this post on GIS stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182444/understanding-difference-between-coordinate-system-and-projection) might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answer and your suggestion! I used the `gdalwarp` to convert the image from the `WGS84` to the `UTM 50N`, then, the pixel size is changed to `(0.28, 0.28)`, it seems reasonable.